# Manipulation with braket notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, linear-algebra

I am still getting used to the braket notation. Is this manipulation correct?
$$
\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\partial^2\phi_n^*}{\partial z^2}
\phi\,dz = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi\left(\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m} 
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}\right)\phi_n^*\,dz = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\phi \hat{K}\phi_n^*\,dz = \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\phi^* \hat{K}\phi_n\,dz \right)^{*} = \langle\phi|\hat{K}|\phi_n\rangle^{*}
$$

Comment: I didn't look over everything but you don't need to add the * at the end of Braket product, that information is inherent into the nature of Bras and Kets.

Comment: ^I didn't look over it either but what @Elvex means is that to take the complex conjugate of a bra-ket scalar just flip the bra and the ket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conclusion is correct, your steps shows maybe you're not quite sure what you're doing, so let me for clarity sake do the problem below.
We know
$$\phi(z)=\langle z|\phi \rangle$$
and
$$\left(\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m} 
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}\right)\phi(z)
=\langle z|\hat{K}|\phi \rangle $$
So in particular:
$$\left(\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m} 
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}\right)\phi_n(z)^*
=\langle z|\hat{K}|\phi_n \rangle^*
=\langle \phi_n|\hat{K}|z \rangle
$$
Therefore
$$
\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\partial^2\phi_n^*}{\partial z^2}
\phi\,dz 
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m} 
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}\right)\phi_n^* \phi\,dz\\
 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
 \langle \phi_n|\hat{K}|z \rangle \langle z|\phi \rangle \,dz=
 \langle \phi_n|\hat{K} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|z \rangle \langle z| \,dz\right) \phi \rangle\\
= 
 \langle \phi_n|\hat{K} |\phi \rangle$$

So your conclusion is correct.